# Website configuraiton for SEO Optimization

Tags: sitemap, seo

In order to promote our product in the various search engines, we've changed our `index.html`
to redirect to `ourapp.example/product/index.html` and moved all our HTML code to `ourapp.example/product/index.html`

Is that the right approach?

Also, is there a canonical place to put files `sitemap.xml` and `BingSiteAuth.xml`?

Comment: Why did you move your `index.html` file to `/product/index.html`?

Answer (score 2):

Always use 301 redirection if you're moving your file locations. That will preserve & pass on page-ranking in Google and will redirect all your hits to the new pages.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, I probably wouldn't have done that. Here's a good read that covers many facits of that type of thinking http://www.seomoz.org/blog/should-i-change-my-urls-for-seo

As far as your second question, the root is the default location.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you do that? In order to promote your product in various search engines? What are you talking about? File names and the keywords in links do have value, but the word products is worthless! Also, why are you pointing to your products page and then to your homepage? Your site should be `ourapp.example/index.html`, not `ourapp.example/products/index.html`?

The placement of your URLs does not matter when it comes to ranking or indexing, and your index page should always be directly after your domain name. Yeah, dude, you aren't promoting anything with that! "products" is not a file, its a directory as you have it stated! Google doesn't care about your directories, they mean nothing. You don't "promote" with file or directory names. If you want Google to be able to tie your content to users search queries then you need to give good descriptive names to your actual files themselves. If your webpage is about "iphone apps for music" then state this in the file name itself like this: `iphone-music-apps.html`. Also, use only hyphens, do NOT use underscores. Hyphens are seen as word separators while underscores are seen as all one word. For instance, `iphone_music_apps.html` would be considered all one word!

It does not matter how you list your content, directories are pointless other than to organize your sites content.

Canonical? Did you specify a preferred URL in your Google webmaster account?

Comment: About underscores and hyphens (dashes): https://blog.codinghorror.com/of-spaces-underscores-and-dashes/